# What is wrong with the inheritance hierarchy in my example?

Tags: c++

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Parent
{
    virtual ~Parent() = default;
};

class Buddy
{
public:
    virtual ~Buddy() = default;
    Buddy(Parent& p) : parent_ { p } {}
    bool IsHovered() const { return is_hovered_; }

private:
    bool    is_hovered_ = false;
    Parent& parent_;
};

class Child : public Parent, public Buddy
{
public:
    Child() : Buddy { *this } {}

    bool BuddyIsHovered() const { return IsHovered(); }
};

int main()
{
    Child c;
    // Expected 'false', but 'true' is always printed.
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << c.BuddyIsHovered() << '\n';
}
```

I can assume that the problem (may be it's an undefined behaviour) occurred because of multiple inheritance and mutual usage of `Child` and `Buddy`. From the other side, I also have assumptions that:

- Compiler firstly allocates memory for `Child`;
- Then compiler runs `Child` constructor; at this point it seems to me, that compiler should know correct addresses for all 3 classes;
- The order of initializations of classes would be: `Parent`, `Buddy`, `Child`. So, when the `Child` constructor_ is running, `Buddy`'s memory has been already initialized, and thus `Buddy` can be used. I mean, `Child`'s code can use `Buddy`'s code, which not touches uninitialized data members of `Buddy`.

Which of my assumptions are correct, and which are wrong?

I use [MSVS 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#2022) and [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14).

Comment: I get only "error: call of overloaded 'Buddy(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)' is ambiguous". Did you actually compile that?

Comment: Yes, MSVS can compile it fine

Comment: Your code says that a child is also both a parent and a buddy. Suggestion: Don't use parent and child in OOP-type inheritance, because it just doesn't make sense in human language.

Comment: Both gcc and clang [REJECTS THIS](https://godbolt.org/z/6eMGecave). Only msvc accepts this. **Looks like another msvc bug**.

Comment: coincidently, after making it compile with gcc, I get the expected `false` https://godbolt.org/z/8svfrePPe

Comment: I believe this can be added to the "bugs in Visual C++" list.

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt. Ha ha. Thank you. I have never thought about that. Child is not a parent indeed. I used to use that terminology because it is very common. I suppose these terms mean that Child inherits properties of Parent.

Comment: I am guessing that VC++ (erroneously) picks the copy constructor, so copies the `Buddy` subobject, which hasn't been initialized.

Comment: Ah, good old MSVC. Great question!

Comment: To answer the titular question, *everything*, and not because some or other bug in initialization.  Just don't do things like that. Repeated non-virtual inheritance is just inviting trouble. Use composition instead.

Comment: And on MSVC: [always use /Za](https://godbolt.org/z/xqM97743r)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI -- But the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions?view=msvc-170) of the `/Za` switch states that _"In C++ compilation mode, the /Za option may cause unexpected behavior and isn't recommended."_ Colin Robertson sheds come light on the reasons [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/issues/801#issuecomment-464248495). And [here](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/1481#issuecomment-464041327) it seems that `/Za` breaks SFINAE when compiling `nlohmann-json` on VS2017.

Comment: @heapunderrun I take it back, I actually wanted to use /permissive- but I mixed it up mentally with /Za, and /permissive- doesn't work here anyway (that is, it results in the program being accepted).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[This is a MSVC bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Ambiguity-in-class-construction-is-not-d/10537718).

What seems to happen is that MSVC interprets

```
Child() : Buddy { *this } {}
```

as

```
Child() : Buddy { static_cast<Buddy &>(*this) } {}
```

Which calls the copy constructor of `Buddy`. That initializes `parent_` with itself, which causes undefined behavior (due to reading it before its lifetime starts, which starts when the initialization is finished).

The fix is to explicitly cast to `Parent &`:

```
Child() : Buddy { static_cast<Parent &>(*this) } {}
```

Comment: I have checked your fix and it works. And your explanation makes sense, I even didn't noticed that wrong constructor could be called

Comment: @Fedor Nah, this causes the same self-initialization UB as OP's code. The correct constructor `Buddy(Parent &p)` isn't called: https://godbolt.org/z/M43aKGshT

Comment: MSVC bug submitted: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Ambiguity-in-class-construction-is-not-d/10537718