# Ambiguity in constructing a class from a child class

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, copy-constructor, ambiguous

This question was inspired by [What is wrong with the inheritance hierarchy in my example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77627045/7325599)

Consider we have a struct `B`, which can be constructed from const reference to another struct `A`. Can `B` be constructed from an object that inherits both `A` and `B`?

```
struct A {};

struct B {
    B() {}
    B(const A&) {}
};

struct C : A, B {};

B b1(C{}); // 1. ok everywhere
C c;
B b2(c);   // 2. ok in MSVC, error in GCC and Clang
```

The first option with construction from temporary `B b1(C{});` is accecpted by all compilers. And the second option with construction from an lvalue `B b2(c);` is accepted only by MSVC, while both GCC and Clang reject it with the ambiguity error:

```
error: call of overloaded 'B(C&)' is ambiguous
note: candidate: 'B::B(const A&)'
note: candidate: 'constexpr B::B(const B&)'
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/hTM6c5M73

Are GCC and Clang really correct in accepting case 1? And is it correct that they change its mind if one additionly declares default copy constructor in `B`:

```
B(const B&) = default;
```

Online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/9j9xeqY3r

Comment: *"if one additionly declares default copy constructor in `B`:"* -- Probably more relevant than declaring the copy constructor is the implicit deletion of the move constructor. (Try instead declaring the destructor, which would also block the compiler-provided move constructor.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`B b2(c);` is ambiguous because `B` has two viable constructors:

```
B(const A&);
B(const B&); // implicitly-declared copy constructor
// implicitly-declared move constructor not viable
```

Both bind the `c` lvalue directly to their respective parameters, but with rank of a derived-to-base conversion sequence (rather than the identity sequence) per [[over.ics.ref]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.ref#1). The conversion sequences are indistinguishable in terms of best overload, because neither is `A` derived from `B` nor is `B` derived from `A`. None of the rules in [[over.ics.rank]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.rank#3) and [[over.ics.rank]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.rank#4) distinguish them.

---

`B b1(C{});` is unambiguous, because there is another viable overload

```
B(B&&); // implicitly-declared move constructor
```

Again, the reference binding is a considered a derived-to-base conversion sequence, i.e. the conversion rank is the same as before.

But because the argument is bound directly to a rvalue reference, it is considered better than the other two overloads which only bind directly to lvalue references per [[over.ics.rank]/3.2.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.ics.rank#3.2.3).

---

Adding `B(const B&) = default;` modifies the overload set by removing the `B(B&&);` move constructor, because it won't be implicitly-declared if there is a user-declared copy constructor per [[class.copy.ctor]/8.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/class.copy.ctor#8.1).

Then `B b1(C{});` is ambiguous between the other two remaining overloads as before.